# Phone menu not showing when clicking on hamburger

Tags: html, css, web-applications, navbar

I was just creating website with html and CSS with a responsive navigation bar and hamburger menu
and which has some content as well in the body of page
but after including contents inside the page the hamburger menu isn't showing
its transition are only you can see
i just wanted the hamburger menu to be shown without disturbing the contents of this page

### code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #2f2f42;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav .logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: teal;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(92, 156, 92);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
  background-color: white;
}

nav .menu-btn i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
    display: block;
  }

  #click:checked~.menu-btn i:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }

  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  #click:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }

  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }

  #click:checked~ul li a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: teal;
  }
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #131314;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 50rem;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  margin-right: 4vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .content {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {

  .content #bor,
  .det,
  .clk {
    display: block;
  }
}

.bor {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.7vw solid white;
}

.det {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 0.6vw solid whitesmoke;
}

.clk {
  float: right;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

h2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.6vw;
  margin: 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw;
  background-color: rgb(64, 80, 113);
  text-align: left
}

#exp {
  padding: 0.8vw;
  margin: 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw 1.9vw;
  text-align: left;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(104, 99, 25);
  color: black;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#foo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Logo img</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
    <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="bor"> this is content heading <br>
    </p><br>
    <span class="det">this is content side</span> <button class="clk">Watch</button><br><br>
    <span class="det">this is content side</span><button class="clk">Watch</button><br><br><br>
    <h2>this is demo</h2>
    <p id="exp">this is content end</p>
  </div>
  <div id="foo">
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; company 2022<br><br> All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `z-index: 9999;` to your `nav ul` and will see that.
It is hidden probably because it is out of the overflow of the parent block.

Try to add a `background-color: #2f2f42;` to your `ul` and job should be done.

### DEMO

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #2f2f42;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav .logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: teal;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(92, 156, 92);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
  background-color: white;
}

nav .menu-btn i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
    display: block;
  }

  #click:checked~.menu-btn i:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }

  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 9999; /** ADDED **/
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: #2f2f42; /** ADDED **/
  }

  #click:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }

  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }

  #click:checked~ul li a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: teal;
  }
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #131314;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 50rem;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  margin-right: 4vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .content {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {

  .content #bor,
  .det,
  .clk {
    display: block;
  }
}

.bor {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.7vw solid white;
}

.det {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 0.6vw solid whitesmoke;
}

.clk {
  float: right;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

h2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.6vw;
  margin: 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw;
  background-color: rgb(64, 80, 113);
  text-align: left
}

#exp {
  padding: 0.8vw;
  margin: 0.8vw 0.8vw 0.8vw 1.9vw;
  text-align: left;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(104, 99, 25);
  color: black;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#foo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Logo img</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
    <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="bor"> this is content heading <br>
    </p><br>
    <span class="det">this is content side</span> <button class="clk">Watch</button><br><br>
    <span class="det">this is content side</span><button class="clk">Watch</button><br><br><br>
    <h2>this is demo</h2>
    <p id="exp">this is content end</p>
  </div>
  <div id="foo">
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; company 2022<br><br> All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```